# Ng build: Optimization error while building in docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

While building an Angular app in docker I get the following error upon reaching npm run build:

```
#11 1.106 > ng build
#11 1.106
#11 4.769 - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
#11 32.23 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
#11 32.24 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
#11 32.25
#11 32.25 Error: Optimization error [runtime.da6be98804527182b005.js]: Error: The service was stopped
#11 32.25     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1258:29
#11 32.25     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:611:9
#11 32.25     at Socket.afterClose (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:589:7)
#11 32.25     at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
#11 32.25     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
#11 32.25     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

My docker file:

```
# BUILD
FROM node:16-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build


# SERVE
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist/portfolio-website /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Angular versions used for development:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.8        
Node: 14.16.0
Package Manager: npm 7.24.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.8 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.8 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.8 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.2.8 (cli-only)
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Comment: if you have specific node 16 features please try using `node:16` otherwise please give `node:lts` a try, `Alpine` images have some weird issues sometimes. Also, check your host machine memory usage over the build timeframe. additionally, please add angular version

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I tried node:16 and node:14.18 but both had the same issue. I even created a blank project and the problems appears, the only difference is this line is added at the before error 
```#11 23.20 /app/src/app/app.component.less - Error: /app/src/app/app.component.less from Css Minimizer```

Comment: Have you made sure you have enough memory while running the build?

Comment: Yes, I have 16 gigs and no other apps running (around 12 gigs free).

Comment: Can you share or link to your blank project for me to debug?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, in Docker file I used Node 14.18 or 16, but to create the container I used node 14.18.

I could either change the version used in Dockerfile to match the one used to create project or (since it was a blank project) install the newer version of node and create a new project with it.