# Angular - Optimization error [main.js]: Error: The service was stopped

Tags: angular, docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an angular application inside the NodeJs app.

My Dockerfile looks like below:

```
FROM node:12.14.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

WORKDIR /app/ng-app

RUN npm install && npm run build


WORKDIR /app

# npm install and delete everything from the ng-app folder except the out directory.
RUN npm install 
RUN find ./ng-app -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -not -name out -exec rm -rf '{}' \;

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run the `docker build -t my-app .` command in my local development environment, everything works fine without any issues.

However, when the same command executes in the AWS CodeBuild pipeline, it throws an error while running the `npm run build` inside the `/app/ng-app` working directory.

```
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/extended : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/flex : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/grid : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/flex-layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-scrollbar/smooth-scroll : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-scrollbar : es2015 as esm2015

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.


Warning: /app/ng-app/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /app/ng-app/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /app/ng-app/src/app/board/service/paper.service.ts depends on 'tree-util'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


Error: Optimization error [main.js]: Error: The service was stopped
    at /app/ng-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1276:29
    at /app/ng-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
    at Socket.afterClose (/app/ng-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:607:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build --output-hashing none`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

The Angular CLI version details on the local development environment are shown below:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.17
Node: 12.14.1
Package Manager: npm 6.13.4
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.17
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.17
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    12.2.17
@angular/flex-layout            12.0.0-beta.35
@angular/material               12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.17
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

A very similar issue has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426626/ng-build-optimization-error-while-building-in-docker) but in my case the node versions seem fine.